# Find the projection of a function $f(x)=1$ to a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

I have to find a projection of a function $f(x)=1$ to a subspace $M$ in $L^2(0,1)$ generated by $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x)=x^2$ and then find the distance between $f$ and subspace $M$.
I post the answer I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the closed subspace $M=[\{x,x^2\}]$ is the unique $ax+bx^2$ such that $(f-ax-bx^2)\perp M$, which gives a $2x2$ system of equations for $a,b$:

$$
      \langle 1-ax-bx^2, x\rangle = 0 \\
      \langle 1-ax-bx^2, x^2\rangle = 0.
$$
This becomes
$$
         \int_{0}^{1}(1-ax-bx^2)x dx = 0 \\
         \int_{0}^{1}(1-ax-bx^2)x^2 dx = 0
$$

or

$$
        \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{1}{4}b=0 \\
        \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}a-\frac{1}{5}b=0.
$$
The distance from $f$ to $M$ is
$$
       \|f-ax-bx^2\| = \left(\int_0^1 (1-ax-bx^2)^2dx\right)^{1/2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Idea of a solution**

First I go for several inner product defined in $L^2$ as
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$$
so I get the following numbers: $\langle1,x\rangle=\frac{1}{2}$, $\langle 1,x^{2}\rangle=\frac{1}{3}$.
Now, I apply the formula for the projection $$P(f)=\langle 1,x\rangle x+\langle 1,x^{2}\rangle x^{2}=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^{2}$$
The distance is given by $\left\Vert f-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{3}x^{2}\right\Vert ^{2}$ and since the norm in $L^2$ is $\Vert f \Vert^2 = \int^1_0|f(x)|^2$dx I obtain a square of the distance:
$$\left\Vert f-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{3}x^{2}\right\Vert ^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}(1-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}  
{3}x^{2})^{2}dx=0.4666...$$
I wonder if I should change the the coefficients in the formula for the $P(f)$ but it seems I got it right

Comment: The formula for projection that you are writing works for orthogonal vectors; are you convinced that $x$ and $x^2$ are orthogonal?

Comment: If I make it $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x)=x^2-\frac{3}{4}x$ I can ensure $<f_1,f_2>=0$. Is it the only problem with the solution?

Comment: Yes, I believe that should be fine then.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for inner product.